# Extension of Python's eval

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = "if X > 3 :\n   print(\"X is Greater\")\nelse :\n   print(\"X is Lesser\")"

""" It prints the string as an indented code of if else statements if X is greater than 3
X is greater else it prints X is lesser"""

X = 6

eval(string)
```

Can `eval()` in python be used in this way or is there anything I'm missing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is used only for expressions. From the documentation

> The ***expression*** argument is parsed and evaluated as a ***Python expression***

Use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) here

```
>>> string = "if X > 3 :\n   print(\"X is Greater\")\nelse :\n   print(\"X is Lesser\")"
>>> X = 6
>>> exec(string)
X is Greater
```

However do note that both the statements are quite risky to use. (See [`eval` really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html))

Comment: really you should avoid both like the plague if you can ... :P but yeah +1

Comment: Hehe. Yeah. I was writing about that